# Rewrite URL using htaccess (avoid a folder from URL)

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i am developing a project in which all the pages are in `views` folder. So if i want to call the pages i have give this `http://example.com/views/home/` in the URL. What i want is to avoid `views` from that URL like this `http://example.com/home/`

How can i do this? I don't know much about writing htaccess. Please help me.

```
http://www.example.com/views/home/
```

to

```
http://www.example.com/home/
```

Answer (score 0):

In an .htaccess file you need to use

```
Deny from  all
```

Put this in *site/view/.htaccess* to make it specific to the view directory

and also Please Visit site http://www.htaccess-guide.com/
http://www.htpasswdgenerator.com/apache/htaccess.html
It is helpful for you
Thank you